# C# How to split advanced?

Tags: c#, .net, math

I need to split a number with decimal places.
An example: I need to do 14525/1024/1024 but in my application, it says

> 0 MB

How to calculate 14525/1024/1024 to

> 00,01 MB

like

> 40.61 MB

(I need to convert bytes to megabytes)

Comment: `14525.0/1024` (please, notice `.0`); again: `14525.0/1024/1024`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use decimal and not int:

```
decimal result = Math.Round((decimal)14525 / 1024 / 1024, 2);
```

Comment: OK, it's worked how to show only two digits form after dot

Comment: @CanÖzkan check the update.

Answer (score 0):

cast any value to `Double` before to do the division